# How to convert every other character in a string to ascii in Python?

Tags: python, string, ascii

I know how to convert characters to ascii and stuff, and I'm making my first encryption algorithm just as a little fun project, nothing serious. I was wondering if there was a way to convert every other character in a string to ascii, I know this is similar to some other questions but I don't think it's a duplicate. Also P.S. I'm fairly new to Python :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please share [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with what you have tried.

Comment: It's a little to me unclear what you're after, do you mean `abcdef` ⇒ `a98c100e102`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ord()` function to get ascii value of a character. You can then do a `chr()` of that value to get the character.